# Yocto mounting initramfs / initrd image to Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, init, yocto, boot

Using Yocto-based tools, I'm able to generate several files for deployment. These involve:

- `sdimg` file for writing to the SD card
- A `cpio.gz` archive (Initramfs)
- `Image-initramfs.bin` (Initramfs)

I would like to activate plymouth in my Embedded board (Raspberry Pi) with a Yocto-based Linux distribution. However I am not sure how to mount the `cpio.gz` archive or `Image-initramfs.bin`. I've read online that vanilla Raspbian has an entry in `/config.txt` in boot partition i.e. `initramfs <file.gz> <start_address>` and also a kernel command line option in `/cmdline.txt` in boot partition i.e. `initrd=<file.gz>`.

What I've tried so far involves both of these approaches. I copy the `cpio.gz` file to the `/boot` in root filesystem partition and configure the aforementioned files, which did not work. To break it down, here is how it looks:

```
 + Boot Partition
 + ---- overlays/
 + ---- config.txt
 + ---- cmdline.txt
 + ---- kernel.img

 + 1.2GB Volume (rootfs)
 + ---- bin/
 + ---- boot/
        +--- <file>.cpio.gz
 + ---- var/
 + ---- usr/
        ....
```

Now, in `config.txt`, I have something like (tried many variations):

```
initramfs <file>.cpio.gz 0x00a00000
ramfsfile="<file>.cpio.gz"
ramfsaddr=0x00a00000
```

In `cmdline.txt`, I have:

```
initrd=<file>.cpio.gz dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
```

However, nothing is enough for the kernel to even give an error. That means, system boots up as normal, and there is no sign of initramfs usage.

Kernel that I compile with yocto is the following:

```
#> uname -a 
#> Linux raspberrypi0-wifi 4.9.77-rt61 #11 PREEMPT RT Tue May 22 01:14:26 +03 2018 armv6l armv6l armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Following kernel config parameters are enabled:

```
#> modprobe configs
#> cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip > kernelconf.txt
...
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_INITRD=y
CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE=""
CONFIG_RD_GZIP=y
```

I don't know what I'm missing here. Anything that catches your attention, please let me know. Any guidance is well appreciated.

Comment: I just noticed something weird. Initramfs should be before rootfs is mounted to I'll have to move my cpio.gz to boot partition even though it does not have enough space. I think this is the right way to proceed. I'll update the question afterwards.

Comment: Still the same behavior. Boots up as usual, but no indication of initramfs.

Comment: i already solved this problem. Will update it.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am trying to do the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to boot into the initramfs by copying the resulting .cpio.gz archive to the boot partition of the sd card.
Then I've edited the config.txt option from

```
#initramfs initramf.gz 0x00800000
```

to

```
initramfs <name-of-the-copied-archive>.cpio.gz
```

After booting the raspberry it boots now into my initramfs image.